# chruby: How to use the default system ruby?

Tags: ruby, chruby

Is there a way to select the default system-wide ruby through `chruby`?

Eg:

```
$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

Comment: Doesn’t `chruby system` work for you?

Comment: It does, thanks. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change back to the default system `ruby`, just use:

```
chruby system
```

If you have more than one system-installed `ruby` (eg `/usr/bin/ruby` and `/usr/local/bin/ruby`) and want to use a different one than is listed by `which ruby`, you can:

```
export RUBIES+=(/usr/local)
```

Then `chruby` will list `usr/local` as a "version" of ruby.

For the general case (possibly multiple rubies in the path), add the following to your shell startup:

```
export RUBIES+=( $(which --all --skip-alias --skip-functions --skip-dot --skip-tilde ruby | sed -n 's/\/bin\/ruby//gp' |sort -u) )
```